# Write a dictionary containing lists in values into text file with keys repeated for each element in the list

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I am new to python and I am working on a project that needs to write a dictionary into a text file. The format is like:

```
{'17': [('25', 5), ('23', 3)], '12': [('28', 3), ('22', 3)], '13': [('28', 3), ('23', 3)], '16': [('22', 3), ('21', 3)], '11': [('28', 3), ('29', 1)], '14': [('22', 3), ('23', 3)], '15': [('26', 2), ('24', 2)]}.
```

as you can see, the values in the dictionary are always lists. I would like to write the below into the text file:
17, 25, 5 \n
17, 23, 3 \n
12, 28, 3 \n
12, 22, 3 \n
13, 28, 3 \n
13, 23, 3 \n
...
\n stands for a new line

Which means, the keys to be repeated for each value inside the list that 'belongs' to those keys. The reason is because I need to read the text file again into database to do further analysis.
Have try searching for an answer for the past few days and tried many ways, just cannot make it into this format. Appreciate if any of you have a solution for this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming values of the hash consist of list with tuple of size 2.

```
>>> f = open('test.txt', 'w')
>>> for key,value in d.iteritems():
...  for v in value:
...     f.write(key + ' ' + v[0] + ' ' + str(v[1]) + '\n')
... 
>>> f.close()
```

Values in test.txt will be

```
11, 28, 3
11, 29, 1
13, 28, 3
13, 23, 3
12, 28, 3
12, 22, 3
15, 26, 2
15, 24, 2
14, 22, 3
14, 23, 3
17, 25, 5
17, 23, 3
16, 22, 3
16, 21, 3
```

Comment: The lists actually contain un-fixed number of values in the hash. So fixing the number of values may not work. But your method could be tranformed into lists with unfixed len i guess. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yes, the method can be updated for unfixed length as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> for k, v in data.items():
...     for t in v:
...        print "%s, %s, %s" % ((k,) +t)
... 
11, 28, 3
11, 29, 1
13, 28, 3
13, 23, 3
12, 28, 3
12, 22, 3
15, 26, 2
15, 24, 2
14, 22, 3
14, 23, 3
17, 25, 5
17, 23, 3
16, 22, 3
16, 21, 3
>>>
```

First get each key and value (which are tuples).  Then loop through the tuples and print each tuple value with the key. Note that dictionaries are not ordered, so the results will not likely be in the order of your dictionary

Comment: Briliant! Well maybe it looks simple for others. But I didn't know with such 'simple' structure code can acomplish this, coz I am new to python i guess. a lot to learn! Thanks a lot Joel goldstick!

Comment: So far this method works well for me in the test data. Btw, I will be writing around 20 million of records to file using this method. With each list inside the dictionary <= 5 elements, i.e. outer loop contains around 4 million. Not sure how long it will take me. I will test it out next..but i guess the outer loop should not be a good concern coz it is hash table. and inside is limited number of less than 5...any comments on time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example showing you how to dump your dictionary to string, first without any particular order and then sorted by keys, pick up what you wish:

```
data = {
    '17': [('25', 5), ('23', 3)],
    '12': [('28', 3), ('22', 3)],
    '13': [('28', 3), ('23', 3)],
    '16': [('22', 3), ('21', 3)],
    '11': [('28', 3), ('29', 1)],
    '14': [('22', 3), ('23', 3)],
    '15': [('26', 2), ('24', 2)]
}

lines = []
for k, v in data.iteritems():
    for tupl in v:
        row = [k] + map(lambda x: str(x), list(tupl))
        lines.append(', '.join(row))

output = '\n'.join(lines)
print output
print '-' * 80

lines = []
for k, v in sorted(data.iteritems()):
    for tupl in v:
        row = [k] + map(lambda x: str(x), list(tupl))
        lines.append(', '.join(row))

sorted_output = '\n'.join(lines)
print sorted_output
```

**EDIT:**

The above code was written to work with python 2.x, here's the 3.x version:

```
data = {
    '17': [('25', 5), ('23', 3)],
    '12': [('28', 3), ('22', 3)],
    '13': [('28', 3), ('23', 3)],
    '16': [('22', 3), ('21', 3)],
    '11': [('28', 3), ('29', 1)],
    '14': [('22', 3), ('23', 3)],
    '15': [('26', 2), ('24', 2)]
}

lines = []
for k, v in data.items():
    for tupl in v:
        row = [k] + list(map(lambda x: str(x), list(tupl)))
        lines.append(', '.join(row))

output = '\n'.join(lines)
print(output)
print('-' * 80)

lines = []
for k, v in sorted(data.items()):
    for tupl in v:
        row = [k] + list(map(lambda x: str(x), list(tupl)))
        lines.append(', '.join(row))

sorted_output = '\n'.join(lines)
print(sorted_output)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer BPL! I am trying to test out your method. But I got the below error. Not sure if it is due to version problem. I am using Python 3.5.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:/Python Projects/Merchant Recommender/Aug 11 Release/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    row = [k] + map(lambda x: str(x), list(tupl))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "map") to list

Comment: @Zhicong Pan That makes sense, you didn't tag your question with python-3 in the first place so I just assumed it didn't matter. I've edited my answer to give you also the working bits with 3.x, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the revised answer! it works perfect now!